# Redirecting website

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have to check the TLS version and then I have to redirect to a different website, I can check the TLS version but I can't get it to redirect to a different website. I'm using notepad to compile and run this code. The code is in Javascript. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
function parseTLSinfo(data, dir) {
  alert(
    data.tls_version.split(' ')[1] < 1.1
    ? 'Error! Your browser only supports ' + data.tls_version + '. Please upgrade to a browser with TLS 1.1 support.'
    : 'Your browser supports ' + data.tls_version + '.'
  );
};
</script>
<script src="https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check?callback=parseTLSinfo"></script>
if (tls_version.split(' ')[1] > 1.0) {
    dir = window.location = "https://www.yahoo.com";
}
else {
    dir = window.location = "https://www.anyurl.com";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `tls_version` defined?

Comment: I use it in my alert, I thought I could just use it again to determine which website to redirect to.

Comment: The version of TLS i get back determines which website I redirect to.

Comment: how do I define tls_version?

Comment: You don't have an opening script tag for your last section of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove variable `dir` from code , it will work

```
dir = window.location...
```

to

```
window.location.href = "your URL"
```

Comment: tried this too, not working. It prints the code on the screen but doesn't redirect to the website

Comment: you didn't define the start script tag for last coding, may be thats why

Comment: also try window.location.reload and location.href

Comment: it says tls_version not defined, how do I define it?

Answer (score 2):

Drop `dir =`. Get your if statement within `parseTLSinfo`. Use `parseFloat()` and `toFixed(1)` to compare numbers

```
<script>
function parseTLSinfo(data, dir) {
  alert(
      data.tls_version.split(' ')[1] < 1.1
      ? 'Error! Your browser only supports ' + data.tls_version + '. Please upgrade to a browser with TLS 1.1 support.'
      : 'Your browser supports ' + data.tls_version + '.'
  );
  if (parseFloat(data.tls_version.split(' ')[1]).toFixed(1) > 1) {
      window.location = "https://www.yahoo.com";
  } else {
      window.location = "https://www.anyurl.com";
  }
}
</script>
<script src="https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check?callback=parseTLSinfo"></script>
```

Comment: did you check whether your code is reaching that area? It seems like you need to open a <script> element right before that

Comment: There are some other problems on this logic. You should have this if statement within your  parseTLSinfo function. You're also possibly comparing strings as if they were float variables in here: tls_version.split(' ')[1] > 1.0

Comment: can you show me how you would do that? I'm trying different ways and nothing is working. please help.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the last answer. I just tried it. Its perfect. Thank you so much.